# How to iterate JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

In the following JSON, I want to fetch all the customers phone and store in a array:

```
{  
   "MetaInformation":{  
      "@TotalResources":1,
      "@TotalPages":1,
      "@CurrentPage":1
   },
   "Customers":[  
      {  
         "@url":"https:\/\/URL/customers\/1",
         "Address1":"Mumbai",
         "City":"Mumbai",
         "CustomerNumber":"1",
         "Email":"xyz@gmail.com",
         "Name":"Saurabh Pradhan",
         "OrganisationNumber":"",
         "Phone":"91xxx",
         "ZipCode":"45153"
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried using following but it keeps throwing me error "Trying to get property of non-object in":

```
$customer_json = json_decode($api->getAllCustomers());    
$customer_json->Customers[0]->Phone;
```

Comment: You code should work just fine. Have you tried printing out the contents of `$customer_json` using `print_r($customer_json);`. Are you sure that  `$api->getAllCustomers()` really returns json and not already decoded json data?

Comment: @Cyclone Thanks for suggesting to print data. As it turned on printing $customer_json was null. I cheked the code of getAllCustomers method again and figured the issue with the return. It is working now.

Comment: Glad you solved it =)

Comment: your syntax for `$customer_json->Customers[0]->Phone` will generate the error reported when `[Customers][0]` is null. With stdObj , php will still try to cascade to the following property (->Phone) and barf on a null object. Is this the real json and real code that produced the error ??? i just coded both your json and code, and it works. As @Cyclone says, if your API returns a stdObj or an assoc array, your json_decode  will give you a null object. Why dont you log the result of `$api->getAllCustomers()` to see what you are really dealing with ?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that PHP representation of JSON object is not an object. PHP uses associative arrays instead. For convinient behavior use:

```
$customer_json = json_decode($api->getAllCustomers(), true);
$customer_json['Customers'][0]['Phone'];
```

Comment: But by default the second argument to `json_decode()` is set to false, which in turn will decode it as objects.

Comment: It's easier to iterate array than object.

Comment: Why is that? Still even so, this is not the solution to the actual problem. Since `$customer_json->Customers[0]->Phone` should be valid.